# CIN Loop Not Working

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin

EDIT:

```
Ctrl-D
```

terminates buffer in linux.

```
Ctrl-Z
```

in Windows.

I should add I use Linux. I use g++.

Now, I'm learning C++ by way of C++ Primer Edition 4.

In an example, this code is given:

```
#include <iostream>
    int main()
    {
        int sum = 0, value;
        // read till end-of-file, calculating a running total of all values read
        while (std::cin >> value)
            sum += value; // equivalent to sum = sum + value
        std::cout << "Sum is: " << sum << std::endl;
        return 0;
     }
```

Now, I enter "3 4 5 6", and I press enter, all I get is a newline, like:

```
1 2 3 4 5
Blank line
```

No output at all.

I refuse to use concepts I haven't learned yet, so far I know no `cin.METHOD` functions, so what's the problem?

Comment: I should add I use LINUX :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input and output are buffered. End the input to terminate the loop by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in the console.

Or read from a file:

```
echo '1 2 3 4 5' > foo.txt
./your-program < foo.txt
```

Or read from standard input via a pipe:

```
echo '1 2 3 4 5' | ./your-program
```

or:

```
./your-program <<< '1 2 3 4 5'
```

(Depending on the terminal emulator you’re using.)